Characterizing the ideals of $R[X, Y]$ and $(R/I)[X]$ generated by a set
I'm trying to develop better intuition into the concept of ideals generated by some subset in polynomial rings (in particular polynomial rings over commutative rings with identity, which I'll name R).
For some reason my text develops the theory in various directions but gives very little concrete examples of what such ideals actually look like.

Is it correct to say that for example in $R[X, Y]$ the ideal $<x, y>$ is simply all the "linear combinations" of $x$ and $y$ with co-efficients being polynomials in $R[X, Y]$? e.g. the general element is of the form $f(x, y)*x + g(x, y)*y$ ? where f, g can be of any degree? in particular this would also include all members of the form $c*x$ for c in R?

if I is a prime ideal in R, what are the maximal ideals of $(R/I)[X]$ ? I'm asking this specifically as it came up in part of a problem I'm trying to solve, and I'm having a hard time trying to think of how this objects would be constructed. Any intuition would be appreciated




Yes. 2. Are you sure the assumption is that $I$ is a prime ideal in $R$, and not a maximal ideal in $R$? You said it's "part" of a problem you're solving. Can you please edit the question to include the entire problem?

